# Multiple guard assign rolling problem in laravel spatie permission

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, guard, laravel-permission

I am using laravel spatie permission package.

I have three guard named...

1. web
2. api
3. customer

### Problem

There is no role named 'customer'

I created a customer role with customer guard.

### auth.php

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

```
    'guards' => [

        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        
    ],
```

Here i changed guard order that that the official documentation followed.

### Main question

The documentation says if i had multiple guard than add `$guard_name` property inside User model. but if i have more guards how to declare this specific guard.

Comment: usually each auth model would have one guard, so you need to complete the multi guard setup first b4 using spatie, 2nd you need to create roles & perms according to each guard, 3rd change the roles check middleware to work with multi guards per route check  otherwise it wont work.